# Why is the env variable not set when entrypoint is echo on docker run?

Tags: docker, docker-entrypoint, docker-run

Why is the environment variable not visible to the command that is run as the entrypoint?
Examples:

```
$docker run -it -e "name=JD" --entrypoint 'echo' ubuntu 'Hello $name'
Hello $name  
$ docker run -it -e "name=JD" --entrypoint 'echo' ubuntu "Hello $name"
Hello
```

But when I start the shell the environment variable is there:

```
$ docker run -it -e "name=JD" ubuntu /bin/bash
root@c3e513390184:/# echo "$name"
JD
```

Why in the first case with the `echo` as entrypoint it does not find the env variable set?

Answer (score 0):

First case

```
docker run -it -e "name=JD" --entrypoint 'echo' ubuntu 'Hello $name'
```

Single quotation mark always prevents string from variable expansion. Whatever you write in single quotes remains unchanged. Try `echo '$PWD'` in your terminal and you will see `$PWD` as the output. Try `echo "$PWD"` and you will get your working directory printed.

Second case

```
docker run -it -e "name=JD" --entrypoint 'echo' ubuntu "Hello $name"
```

Your code is being expanded **before** running Docker. Your shell expands whole string and then executes it. At this moment you dont have `$name` declared and you get it empty. That means inside container you get `"Hello "` command, not `"Hello $name"`.

If you want to echo environment variable from inside container, simplest way is to **wrap script into sh-file** to prevent its expansion and pass this file to container.

Third case is obvious I guess and doesn't need explanation.

Comment: The reason I used single quotes in the first case was exactly so that the variable is not substituted by my shell but passed to docker for parameter substitution. I also tried `'hello \"$name\"'` but that gave an error. So there is no way to do this without a wrapper script?